# White color not visible in toolbar

Tags: android-layout

I have a green toolbar in my layout and I inserted a textview into it to center the text horizontally. I want the text of the toolbar to be white and I choose the color white for that. However, the white text is barely visible. Can anyone help? I'd appreciate it.

[image]

Here is the XML code of the TextView:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"


    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="ExtraText">




    '<!--Learning: The following lines define a toolbar -->'

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_mainActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:background="#435cb53f"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:titleTextColor="@android:color/holo_green_light" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Bestellen_Button"
        android:layout_width="255dp"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/Bestellen_Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.584"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.461" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Statistik_Button"
        android:layout_width="256dp"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/Statistik_Button"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.875" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="147dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="Test"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.744"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.203"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="153dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_ToolBar_MainActivity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TestText"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar_mainActivity"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.535"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/toolbar_mainActivity"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.421"
        tools:text="TestText" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Is it that the contrast isn't high enough between the two colors, is it that the font is too thin? Maybe you can add a screenshot to make your problem clearer.

Comment: I added a screenshot from Android Studio. On the blueprint you can see the text "TestText" is visible but on the real layout, it is barely visible, as I choose white as the color

Comment: what's the xml for toolbar_mainActivity?And did you declare it before or after the TextView in your layout file?

Comment: toolbar_mainActivity is the toolbar for the main activity. And it is defined before the TextView

Comment: I tried to change the order meaning that the TextView is defined after the toolbar. But this did not change anything. The white text is still barely visible.

Comment: Does nobody have a clue? This is really kind of strange. I mean I only want to have a visible white font. Maybe the TextView is not the right item for that?

Comment: can you  post the whole xml file? Or better yet a minimal example of the xml file where the problem occurrs? My guess is that something transparent (e.g. the toolbar) is overlying the TextView because the text color does not actually look white. But from just the TextView I can't tell.

Comment: I posted the whole xml file. Any ideas now? I'd appreciate an answer.

Comment: If one of the posted solutions below solved your problem, accept as answer and upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel the reason why it's happening is due to elevation. Since the elevation of the Toolbar is 4dp, it is above the textView.

I guess if you add `android:elevation="4dp"` or anything more than 4dp, you will be able to see the text clearly.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the elevation you are using in your toolbar. This means, the toolbar is lying "on top" of the rest, therefore overlying the TextView. And this means that the text is not showing as you want it to.

**Solution 1**
Get rid of the elevation altogether and your text will show in plain white.

**Solution 2**
I think it should also work if you put both, the toolbar and the TextView into another Layout within your ConstraintLayout (e.g. into a RelativeLayout) and add the elevation to that layout instead of the toolbar. This way both of the elements should have the same elevation without casting a shadow upon each other. But I'm not entirely sure about this solution, you'll have to try it to see if it works.

[Here](https://material.io/design/environment/elevation.html#elevation-in-material-design) is some additional information about elevation.